# Webfont for Apple Mail Signature possible?

Tags: html-email, webfonts, apple-mail

This is a very general question regarding Apple Mail. An HTML signature is to be created for this. That worked so far. Now the customer wants a web font. As far as I know, I cannot integrate these using an inline CSS. On the other hand, I can't write a head tag in the signature either.
Is there a way to embed a web font in Apple Mail or is it not?

Answer (score 0):

Web fonts work the same way in web and emails. You declare it using `@font-face`. The support for web fonts however is limited in emails.

The following email clients have suport for web fonts:

- iOS Mail
- Apple Mail
- Android (default mail client, not Gmail app)
- Outlook 2000
- Outlook.com app
- Thunderbird

All other email clients will resort to fall back fonts or the fonts coded into email clients will/might* show:

- Apple Mail = Helvetica
- Gmail = Arial
- Microsoft Outlook`*` = Calibri

Hope that answers your question.

Source: [Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/web-fonts-in-email/)

```
    * Defaults to Times new Roman if not declared/coded properly.
```